# How to disable Winter Bash?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

How do I disable the Winter Bash icon (near the top right hand corner) and hats?

I just find it visually confusing and distracting. I find Stack Exchange web pages complicated enough at all times, and this Winter Bash thing is just one more thing I can do well without.

(The same would also apply to April Fools and Easter Eggs.)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a uBlock-compatible ad blocker, you can add the following rule:

```
##.icon-winterbash
```

to permanently hide the icon.

If you use uBlock origin, you can simply right-click the element and select "Block element..." instead:

[image]